# I am getting ssh authentication error when i execute terraform file from Go

Tags: go, terraform

I am executing a terraform file from a GO code. I am getting the below error.

```
 timeout - last error: SSH authentication failed (ec2-user@3.142.149.63:22):
    ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none
    publickey], no supported methods remain
    
    Error: file provisioner error
```

But, When I execute it manually from the working directory of the terraform file. It works without errors and keys are in the Paths I have used.

Below is my GO code

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/hashicorp/go-version"
    "github.com/hashicorp/hc-install/product"
    "github.com/hashicorp/hc-install/releases"
    "github.com/hashicorp/terraform-exec/tfexec"
)

func main() {

    installer := &releases.ExactVersion{
        Product: product.Terraform,
        Version: version.Must(version.NewVersion("1.0.6")),
        Timeout: 1000000000000000,
    }

    execPath, err := installer.Install(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error installing Terraform: %s", err)
    }

    workingDir := "C:/Users/XYZ/Learnings/Terraform JMeter/terraform-aws-jmeter-distributed-load-test-infra"
    tf, err := tfexec.NewTerraform(workingDir, execPath)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error running NewTerraform: %s", err)
    }

    err = tf.Init(context.Background(), tfexec.Upgrade(true))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error running Init: %s", err)
    }

    

    err = tf.Apply(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error running Apply: %s", err)
    }

    state, err := tf.Show(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error running Show: %s", err)
    }

    fmt.Println(state.FormatVersion) // "0.1"
    

    }
```

Can someone help me? Below I have added the file provisioner part

```
 connection {
    type        = "ssh"
    user        = "ec2-user"
    private_key = file("C:/Users/XYZ/Learnings/GO/go-terraform.pem")
    host        = self.public_ip
  }
 
  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "Data98UserName.csv"
    destination = "/home/ec2-user/Data98UserName.csv"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

When the execution mode in terraform cloud is changed from local to cloud, the issue was fixed for me.